# Mutagen does not recognize MP4 iTunes voice memo tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, itunes, mp4, mutagen

### Problem

I have recorded some voice memos on iPhone. 
I have added titles for different events. 
After synchronizing, those appear in a separate album. 
In iTunes they are listed with titles, but the MP4-files are named by the following format: `yyyymmdd hhmmss.m4a` (AAC encoded).

In order to move the files I would like to rename those files with a little python-script using [mutagen](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp4.html?highlight=mp4).

```
import mutagen.mp4 as m
f = m.MP4("file.m4a")
print(f.tags)
print(f.MP4Tags())
# f['\xa9nam'] = "test" # works
print(f['\xa9nam']) # only works if edited by previous line or in iTunes
```

However, `mutagen` does not recognize the tags correctly, but only after they have been edited (in iTunes). The output of `f.tags` looks like this:

```
{'----:com.apple.iTunes:iTunSMPB': [MP4FreeForm(b' 00000000 00000840 000003E0 0000000007823BE0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000', <AtomDataType.UTF8: 1>)], '©too': ['com.apple.VoiceMemos (iOS 10.2)']}
```

and `f.MP4Tags()` yields `{}`.
After editing the title it does appear in `f.tags`:

```
{'©nam': ['test'], '----:com.apple.iTunes:iTunSMPB': [MP4FreeForm(b' 00000000 00000840 000003E0 0000000007823BE0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000', <AtomDataType.UTF8: 1>)], '©too': ['com.apple.VoiceMemos (iOS 10.2)']}
```

### Question

> How to read original `*.m4a` - iPhone voice memo tags ?

Comment: Seems like you'd probably have more luck raising this with the developers of mutagen...

Comment: FYI best place for this is usually to start a discussion on the [Mutagen issues](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/issues).

Comment: @JonClements and declension thank you for your hints! I was able to figure out where the information is stored; see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/issues/323) the **title is not stored inside the file tags** but only in the iTunes library file.

One can [set iTunes to create an `*.xml`](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201610) containing this information in a readable fashion.

[A similar question on apple-support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7037821?start=0&tstart=0) was answered with a [link](http://samsoft.org.uk/iTunes/scripts.asp#CustomRenamer) to a basic script for renaming the voice memos; reading exactly from that.